# How to use positioned scroll list inside the nested scrollview

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my app, I need to use Sliver appbar, pinned header and list with positioned scroll list.
So I have tried Nested scrollview with scrollable_positioned_list.
But the list is not scrolled fully when **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics** is used. If I remove this, list scrolled separately.

```
 NestedScrollView(
        controller: model.scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder:
            (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          // These are the slivers that show up in the "outer" scroll view.
          return <Widget>[
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle:
                  NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
              sliver: SliverSafeArea(
                top: false,
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: 320,
                  elevation: 0,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  backgroundColor: model.isToolbarTitleVisible
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  title: AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: model.toolbarTitleOpacity,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                      child: Text(
                        tr(LocaleKeys.myContacts),
                        style: TextStyles.appBarTitle(context,
                            color: CustomColors.darkBlueGreyColor),
                      )),
                  leadingWidth: 64,
                  leading: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 4),
                    decoration: model.user!.photoProfile != null
                        ? BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
                            color: CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image:
                                    NetworkImage(model.user!.photoProfile!),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover))
                        : const BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
                            color: CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor),
                  ),
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    background: Container(
                      height: 320,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            tr(LocaleKeys.myContacts),
                            style: TextStyles.labelTextCustomStyle(context,
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                letterSpacing: -0.5),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            tr(LocaleKeys.cardsRegistered,
                                namedArgs: <String, String>{
                                  'count': model.count.toString()
                                }),
                            style: TextStyles.labelTextCustomStyle(
                              context,
                              textColor: CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 60, right: 60, top: 28),
                            child: SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    style: ButtonStyles
                                        .ButtonWithTextAndIconStyle(
                                            radius: 25.0,
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor,
                                            elevation: 0),
                                    icon: const Icon(BimsCardIcons.ic_scan,
                                        size: 24),
                                    label: Text(tr(LocaleKeys.scanCard),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyles
                                            .buttonTextCustomStyle(context,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                fontSize: 16.0)))),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    Visibility(
                      visible: model.isAuthenticated,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 12, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
                          color: CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor,
                        ),
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 8, 10, 8),
                          child: Icon(CardIcons.ic_sync),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: model.isAuthenticated,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 12, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                              (model.isToolbarTitleVisible) ? 16 : 20)),
                          color: CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor,
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 8, 10, 8),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                                padding: model.isToolbarTitleVisible
                                    ? const EdgeInsets.all(0)
                                    : const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  CardIcons.ic_qr_code,
                                  size: 24,
                                )),
                            Visibility(
                              visible: !model.isToolbarTitleVisible,
                              child: Text(
                                tr(LocaleKeys.myCard),
                                style: TextStyles.buttonTextCustomStyle(
                                    context,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: !model.isAuthenticated,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 12, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          color: CustomColors.dirtyBlueColor,
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 11, 20, 11),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            tr(LocaleKeys.login),
                            style: TextStyles.buttonTextCustomStyle(context,
                                fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: _SearchHeader(
                  search: CupertinoTextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                placeholder: tr(LocaleKeys.search),
                style: TextStyles.labelTextCustomStyle(
                  context,
                  textColor: CustomColors.darkBlueGreyColor,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
                placeholderStyle: TextStyles.labelTextCustomStyle(
                  context,
                  textColor:
                      CustomColors.darkBlueGreyColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
                prefix: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    size: 24,
                    color: CustomColors.darkBlueGreyColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 24.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 24.0),
                  child: model.isBlocked
                      ? const Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                          ),
                        )
                      : ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                          itemCount: model.keys.length,
                          itemScrollController: model.itemScrollController,
                          itemPositionsListener:
                              model.itemPositionsListener,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            String item = model.keys[index];
                            List<Widget> list = model.createContactItems(
                                context, model.contacts[item]);
                            return Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                _header(context, item),
                                Column(
                                  children: list,
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              Container()
            ],
          ),
        ))
```

Kindly suggest some plugin or example to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Updated code. Thank you

Comment: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics means your list not allow scrolling

Comment: Is there any other option to use sliverappbar along with scrolable positioned list

Comment: try with https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#stack

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do sticky headers?

If so, you can try this https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers.
And use "Listview" with "NeverScrollableScrollPhysics".

```
   StickyHeader(
        header: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text('Header #$index',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        content: ListView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          ...
        ),
      );
```